# could not locate oozie share lib

Tags: hadoop, oozie

The details of my oozie job are given below:

[image]

I am getting the following error:

```
57-oozie-oozi-W@MR] Error starting action [MR]. ErrorType [FAILED], ErrorCode [EJ001], Message [Could not locate Oozie sharelib]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: Could not locate Oozie sharelib
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.addSystemShareLibForAction(JavaActionExecutor.java:603)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.addAllShareLibs(JavaActionExecutor.java:698)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.setLibFilesArchives(JavaActionExecutor.java:689)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:884)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1135)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:228)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:63)
```

I have put lib in /user/root ,user/oozie .But still it is not able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the Oozie documentation a MapReduce action should not care about Shared Libs:

> *The Oozie sharelib TAR.GZ file bundled with the distribution contains
>   the necessary files to run Oozie map-reduce streaming, pig, hive,
>   sqooop, and distcp actions ... other actions (mapreduce, shell, ssh,
>   and java) do not require the sharelib to be installed.*

Anyway, the root dir for the Shared Libs should be something like

```
/user/oozie/share/lib/
```

Your setup is probably missing the "share" part (see [Quick Start](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/DG_QuickStart.html#Oozie_Share_Lib_Installation))

And if you want to try a non-default location then look at the documentation for "sharelib create" command, and also for specifics about Oozie server config.

http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/AG_Install.html#Oozie_Share_Lib
plus #Oozie_Server_Setup